# As a contractor, how to fill in those end-of-year weeks?

Tags: software-industry, contractors, freelancing, sales

- For 46 weeks of the year, there's lots of freelance and contract work
- However, I find that right around *now* it's basically<sup>[2]</sup> hard to find any contracts or freelance work.

I find there's just not much there until about *January 15*.

Surprisingly this seems to be a worldwide phenomenon. Global new year!

Obviously all contractors/freelancers financially plan for this.

But, is there any specific tricks to **find more works at this time of the year**, which freelance/contractor software engineers have found?

I thought this might be an interesting question for the site, with broad application.

---

*[2] it starts at about 2pm London time, on the Thursday before December!*

Comment: Your question basically seems to boil down to "I'm having trouble finding freelance work near the holiday period". Add a concrete goal you want to address, and cut some irrelevant chatter: the intro "apology", the non-redominantly-Christian paragraph, the "note, relax! and! enjoy! your! self!" comment paragraph, and the "footnotes" part are unneeded.

Answer (score 8):

This is what any decent contractor will think and plan for.

Just assume that you'll be out of work for a month or so between contracts and budget accordingly.

It doesn't matter that this is the software industry, it doesn't matter that it's the end of the year.  You just make the assumption that:

A) Your cushy contract isn't going to be extended at the end of the term
B) It's going to take a while to pick up a new contract
C) The rate for your new contract might not keep you in the lifestyle to which you've become accustomed

Budget, budget, budget.

Comment: ... and set your rate accordingly.  This is why contractors have to charge a much higher hourly rate than salaried people in order to have approximately the same income.

Comment: -1 I don't think this is answering the question. It mentions boredom rather than finances.

Comment: Was a contractor for over a decade. This is just how it's done in all industries. You will be out of work sometimes and you set your rates and budget accordingly.